# Como buscar id separado por "," corretamente?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Eu tenho uma tabela chamado atendimento, dentro dela tenho um campo chamado encaminhamento, no campo encaminhamento eu salvo os ID dos "tipos de encaminhamentos" que tenho cadastrado na tabela cad_encaminhamentos separados por "," . Preciso de contar a quantidade de encaminhamento realizado de um determinado periodo, e preciso saber a quantidade de cada um. Então fiz um loop utilizando o comando for para ser pesquisado encaminhamento por encaminhamento dessa maneira:

```
for($n=1;$n<= $row[0];$n++){

$quant_enc = "SELECT encaminhamento FROM atendimento WHERE encaminhamento LIKE '%$n%' AND data_atendimento BETWEEN '$inicio' AND '$fim'";


    $ex_enc = mysqli_query($conn,$quant_enc);
    $row_quant = mysqli_num_rows($ex_enc);
    $quant[$n]=$row_quant;`
```

O problema que eu estou tendo , é que quando existe por exemplo : Encaminhamento com id 12, e outro com id 112, com LIKE %12% , conta duas vezes pois no numero 112 considera 12 também. Essa é a melhor forma de conseguir essa informação ou existe maneiras mais práticas? Ou como obter somente o código que realmente estou pesquisando ?

[image: Campo onde é armazado os ID separado por "," varchar 255]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para achar um valor separado por vírgulas dentro de uma *string* existe o `FIND_IN_SET`.

Aplicado ao seu caso:

```
SELECT encaminhamento FROM atendimento WHERE FIND_IN_SET( '12', encaminhamento );
```

Só que a performance não é boa, assim como o `LIKE` usado com `%` na esquerda, não aproveita índices. Talvez seja  melhor refatorar de alguma maneira. Se for para pouco volume de dados, talvez não seja problemático.

### Manual:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: Funcionou ! Muito obrigado mesmo, acredito que pela performasse não será o problema, pois essa pesquisa será executada 1 vez por mês para tirar o relatório mensal.